# Problem with two-dimensional array and for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Today I restarted coding after a few months and tried do do Snake in the console.
I tried to do it with a two-dimensional array and 2 for-loops.

```java
public static void clearWindow() {
    String[][] board = new String[9][]; {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            for(int o=0; 0<8; o++) {
                board[i][o]="O ";
                System.out.print(board[i][o]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
}}}
```

The Code has 2 mistakes which I can't find. The first one happens after 10 'O's are printed. It has something to do with `board[i][o]="O ";`

The second mistake is the `System.out.println("");` . With this line, the code won't even run.

Answer (score 1):

You have written `0 < 8` and not `o < 8` in the condition of the inner loop. Zero will always be smaller than 8 that's why you end up in an endless loop and that's why your second *Sysout* will never get reached.

I would recommend using the well known names for running variables *i* for the outer loop and *j* for the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the typo in the loop `for(int o=0; 0<8; o++)` there are other issues:

1. 2D array `board` is not initialized properly which causes `NullPointerException` in line `board[i][o]="O ";`
2. Unneeded statement block after initialization of `board`
3. Actual dimensions of the `board` should be used in the loops.
4. You seem to be creating a "clean" window, so you should return the `board` from this method.
   That being said, the code may be changed like this:

```java
public static String[][] clearWindow() {
    String[][] board = new String[9][9];
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j]="O ";
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return board;
}
```